# Time interval in sub class

Tags: java, android

I need to have a time interval in a sub class, but I can't extends the Timer class, because I already extends another class. And I have tested some other variations, but it seems that it's not working since my class isn't the MainActivity and don't have any onCreate method!?

So how can I solve this?

EDIT: I'm doing a simple game with some sprite objects. And when a sprite object is hit, then I want to fade away it with setAlpha() in intervals. That's what I need the time interval to in each sprite object. And I'm going to activate the fading with a boolean value. I guess I need a Thread for each subclass or could I do something static to get the interval time!? A thread for each subclass, would that affect the performance negative?

Could this be done in some simple way?

EDIT 2: I found this code abount

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

And this, but I'm not sure how I should call it or how I would do to be able to call a method in each sprite of the list of sprites? Some help to develop this would be helpful!

```
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    // Do some stuff that you want to do here

// You could do this call if you wanted it to be periodic:
    mHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000 );

    }
};
```

Comment: Can Thread.sleep() be considered?

Comment: Please specify your requirements in more detail. Unless we know more, we cannot possibly give reasonable advice. For example, one question is: Which timebase does your time interval have to relate to? Should the device wake up after the interval if it went to sleep in the meantime? How long is the interval? Which prcision do you need? Etc.

Comment: But I guess this would affect the rest of the code since this is a game and I'm using implements Runnable. If I understand it right, then all moving objects would be affected!? I have tested to create a new Thread for each subclass, but couldn't get it to work. Any adeas how I can solve this?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to extend the Timer class. Why not just have a Timer member variable?

Comment: Can you show me some example code of a Timer member variable?

Comment: I just read your update. A thread per sprite is definitely not what you'd usually go for. Why don't you maintain a list of the sprites which are supposed to fade out and use `Handler.postDelayed()`.

Comment: I have all my sprites in a list that I handle in a manager class. But I need to see an example to understand how to use Handler.postDelayed() with my list?

Comment: Really? Why do you need an example?

Comment: Is that so strange!? I haven't used Handler.postDelayed() before and it's hard to understand how it works and how I should implement it